# Does my program architecture make sense? AngularJS + ASP.NET Web API + SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, architecture

I have been getting a bit lost in the creation of my program architecture and I want to take a step back to see if I'm approaching it correctly.

I am wondering if my setup makes sense.  I'm starting to think it doesn't.

I am creating intranet applications (We were creating Internet applications, but now the scope has changed).  We use an onsite Active Directory (Windows Server 2012 R2).  We have a SQL Server Database.

I have been building Front End Angular applications and ASP.NET Web API's to push and pull data.  I am now implementing Authentication with Auth0 and it's been a nightmare.

What kind of program architecture would you setup in this scenario?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server** + **Asp.Net Web Api** + **Angular JS** forms a perfect architecture for building Single Page Applications (SPAs). This architecture is useful for building desktop like web applications, i.e. apps that runs over web but works like desktop apps.

If you can be more specific about the problem you are facing, you will be able to get better recommendations from so.

Comment: does it make sense for building intranet (emphasis on the intrA) applications?  Does  it integrate well with Active Directory?  I thought ASP.NET web API is for internet (emphasis on the e).

Comment: @NickGrover You're getting way too hung up over Internet vs Intranet. There's not much difference, other than an Intranet isn't publicly accessible. The same technologies that work for one will work for the others.

Comment: Be it Intranet or Internet, all of these (HTML, JS, Asp.Net etc) are collectively known as "Web Technologies". The web technologies works same irrespective of the scope of network in which they exist. If you want to reduce complexity, an option is to just build Desktop app that talks directly with database server since its running on a private network.

Answer (score 0):

This architecture is widely adopted in many scenarios such as SPAs. With it, you will be able to keep your front-end highly decoupled from your backend services being able to support multiple front-ends on the same set of services and run quite a few integration scenarios.

Some of the downsides of such an approach will be the extra layer of complexity added to the application (which might force you to write more tests and handle different failure scenarios that wouldn't happen otherwise, for an example) and authentication routines since you will need to authenticate two heterogeneous environments (the .NET/IIS one and the JS/Angular one).

As for the authentication pain, token-based auth schemes seem the current way to go (such as Auth0) since they let you keep and send an environment-agnostic token which will be used by different layers of your architecture.

In that sense, your architecture makes sense.

However, since you're feeling some pain in its implementation, you might want to ask yourself if you really needed all of these. When you choose an architecture, you do so trying to accomplish some specific goals (multiple front-ends? specific performance requirements? maintainability? auditability?) and the more goals you try to accommodate in your architecture the more complex will become up to a point where the pains start outweighing the benefits.

So, what were you trying to achieve in the first place?